# AttributeError at /admin/login/ 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I come across this error when I tried to login to my admin page.

```
AttributeError at /admin/login/

'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py in import_string, line 15
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\Scripts\python.exe
```

traceback :

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  361.             self.each_context(request),

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in each_context
  284.             'available_apps': self.get_app_list(request),

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in get_app_list
  451.         app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in _build_app_dict
  397.             has_module_perms = model_admin.has_module_permission(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in has_module_permission
  476.         return request.user.has_module_perms(self.opts.app_label)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in has_module_perms
  438.         return _user_has_module_perms(self, module)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in _user_has_module_perms
  199.     for backend in auth.get_backends():

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in get_backends
  38.     return _get_backends(return_tuples=False)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _get_backends
  27.         backend = load_backend(backend_path)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in load_backend
  21.     return import_string(path)()

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py" in import_string
  15.         module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

And I don't know why this error is raised and I don't know how exactly to fix it. I do search about this error and most of them when they try to run the `collectstatic` command. The error is caused by the comma and I did delete the comma behind the closed bracket here :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS= (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
        )
```

But I still can't access to my admin page .

I did follow to the traceback :

```
def import_string(dotted_path):
    """
    Import a dotted module path and return the attribute/class designated by the
    last name in the path. Raise ImportError if the import failed.
    """
    try:
        module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
    except ValueError:
        msg = "%s doesn't look like a module path" % dotted_path
        six.reraise(ImportError, ImportError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])

    module = import_module(module_path)
```

I try to make my own custom registration page for user and super user.

**init**.py :

```
def load_backend(path):
    return import_string(path)()


def _get_backends(return_tuples=False):
    backends = []
    for backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
        backend = load_backend(backend_path)
        backends.append((backend, backend_path) if return_tuples else backend)
    if not backends:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            'No authentication backends have been defined. Does '
            'AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS contain anything?'
        )
    return backends


def get_backends():
    return _get_backends(return_tuples=False)
```

Comment: `dotted_path` is supposed to be a `string`, you passed a `tuple`.

Comment: can you explain more ? i kind new in django . im so sorry @MD.KhairulBasar

Comment: Can you show the code where are you calling `import_string()` ?

Comment: The problem is **not** in your STATIC settings. Please post your URLs and view.

Comment: i did manage to fix the error but after that i get a new error . LookupError: App 'custom_user' doesn't have a 'customuser' model

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is incorrect.  If you refer to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs it indicates that you should define your `STATICFILES_DIRS` as a list:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
]
```

It's hard to diagnose what the cause is because there is no stacktrace, otherwise you could find exactly where that exception is coming from.  I think its related to this setting though.

Also, when you use a tuple without the comma it just evaluates it like an expression.  I'll give an example:

```
a = (
    'I think this is a tuple'
)
assert isinstance(a, tuple), "This is not a tuple"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "`<stdin>`", line 1, in `<module>`
>   AssertionError: This is not a tuple

Whereas if you do the same with a comma:

```
a = (
    'I know this is a tuple',
)
assert isinstance(a, tuple), "This is not a tuple"
```

You will get no such AssertionError for this second example.